# Record feed from camera2 device and send it over a network

Tags: android, android-camera2

I am developing an application which is supposed to capture the camera preview/video from camera2 api and send the ByteArray to another device connected over a network(preferrably wifi). But I couldn't get the proper preview similar to that of PreviewCallBack in the deprecated api. I know that the code won't be of much help but still I am adding it. Please guide me through any solution. Any links will also be appreciated. Thanks..

```
  private void createPreview() throws CameraAccessException {
            SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture = mTexture.getSurfaceTexture();
            assert surfaceTexture != null;
            surfaceTexture.setDefaultBufferSize(size.getWidth(), size.getHeight());
            //Surface surface = new Surface(surfaceTexture);

            ImageReader imageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(size.getWidth(), size.getHeight(), ImageFormat.JPEG, 2);
            imageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(reader -> {
                Image image = reader.acquireLatestImage();

                ByteBuffer byteBuffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
                image.close();
            }, null);

            captureRequestBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);

            captureRequestBuilder.addTarget(imageReader.getSurface());

            cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(imageReader.getSurface()), new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
                    cameraCaptureSession = session;
                    updatePreview();
                }

                @Override
                public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {

                }
            }, null);        

        }
```

Comment: What exact part are you having problems with? Setting up camera2, accessing the Images from the ImageReader, etc... your question is too broad right now.

Comment: I am facing problems getting the video feed from camera2 in a byte array so that it can be transferred as the server response